# Find the sum of the series: $\frac{1}{1*2} - \frac{1}{3*2^3} + \frac{1}{5*2^5} - \frac{1}{7*2^7}+\dots$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

$$\frac{1}{1*2} - \frac{1}{3*2^3} + \frac{1}{5*2^5} - \frac{1}{7*2^7}+\dots$$ 
I made a series to get $$\sum_{n=0}^\inf \frac{(-1)^n}{(1+2n)*2^{1+2n}}$$ but what series can it manipulate and simplify to?

Comment: Take a close look at the Series of the arctangent

Comment: This is an instance of the Gregory's series.

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 3):

The geometric series gives $$\frac{1}{1+x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^{2n}, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{when } \lvert x \rvert < 1.$$ Then $$\frac{1}{1+x^2} - 1 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^{2n},$$ for such $x$. Integrating from $x=0$ to $x=1/2$ (and integrating term-by-term in the sum, which is justifies by uniform convergence of the sum) gives $$\arctan\left( \tfrac 1 2\right) - \tfrac{1}{2} = \sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^n \left( \tfrac{1}{2}\right)^{2n+1}}{2n+1} = \sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)2^{2n+1}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)$ denote the power series for $|x|<1$ given by

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\int_0^x t^{2n}\,dt\\\\
&=\lim_{N\to \infty}\int_0^x \sum_{n=0}^N (-t^2)^n \,dt\\\\
&=\lim_{N\to \infty}\int_0^x \frac{1-(-t^2)^{N+1}}{1+t^2}\,dt \tag 1 \\\\
&=\int_0^x\frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt \tag 2\\\\
&=\arctan(x)
\end{align}$$

where the Dominated Convergence Theorem justifies our passing the limit in $(1)$ under the integral and arriving at $(2)$.  Now, setting $x=1/2$, we obtain the coveted result

$$f(1/2)=\arctan(1/2)$$